# Searching for string and wrapping entire word with an element

Tags: jquery

I want to search for a string in a specific element and wrap the full text with a span, I also want it to match part of the word and wrap the entire word....

My attempt so far:

```
function filterSearchWords(){
    var query = $("#searchquery").val();

    go(query);
    function go(query) {
        $(".search-result:contains(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.split(query).join("<span class='search-enlight'>" + query + "</span>");
        });

        console.log(query);
    }
}
```

However, now I want it to wrap the ENTIRE word, like lets say I am sorting on the string: Enlight, it should wrap Enlighten. Is this possible to do? Also, making it not caring about uppercase, so it matches with enlight and Enlight

UPDATE:

```
function filterSearchWords() {
    var query = $("#searchquery").val();

    go(query);
    function go(query) {
        $(".search-result p:contains(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.replace(query, "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>", 'gi');
        });
        $(".search-result h2 a:contains(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.replace(query, "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>", 'gi');
        });
        console.log(query);
    }
}
```

This is still not working, its not matching a word that has a uppercase, and it does not wrap the entire word. Any help :/